# How do I query for only superclass entities in a jpql query?

Tags: orm, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, jpql

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="orderType", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue(value="BASE")
@Table(name = "orders")
public class OrderEntity implements Serializable {
...
```

and

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="RECURRING")
public class RecurringOrderEntity extends OrderEntity{
...
```

I can find all the subclasses (RecurringOrderEntity) with the following jpql:

```
Query q = em.createQuery(
                "SELECT o from RecurringOrderEntity o where "
                + "o.cancellationDate is null "
                + "and o.maxOccurrences = o.occurrence");
```

What is the JPQL syntax for finding *only* entities that are *not* instances of *RecurringOrderEntity*?

I am using Eclipselink 2.0.0 as the JPA provider.

thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> What is the JPQL syntax for finding only entities that are not instances of RecurringOrderEntity?

Use an entity type expression with the `TYPE` operator. Something like this (not sure about the exact query you want but you get the idea):

```
SELECT o 
FROM OrderEntity o 
WHERE TYPE(o) <> RecurringOrderEntity
  AND o.cancellationDate is null
  AND o.maxOccurrences = o.occurrence
```

Below, the relevant section of the JPA 2.0 specification:

> #### 4.6.17.4 Entity Type Expressions
>
> An entity type expression can be used
>   to restrict query polymorphism. The
>   TYPE operator returns the exact type
>   of the argument.
>
> The syntax of an entity type
>   expression is as follows:
>
> ```
> entity_type_expression ::=
>        type_discriminator |
>        entity_type_literal |
>        input_parameter
> type_discriminator ::=
>        TYPE(identification_variable |
>             single_valued_object_path_expression |
>             input_parameter )
> ```
>
> An *entity_type_literal* is
>   designated by the entity name.
>
> The Java class of the entity is used
>   as an input parameter to specify the
>   entity type.
>
> **Examples:**
>
> ```
> SELECT e
> FROM Employee e
> WHERE TYPE(e) IN (Exempt, Contractor)
>
> SELECT e
> FROM Employee e
> WHERE TYPE(e) IN (:empType1, :empType2)
>
> SELECT e
> FROM Employee e
> WHERE TYPE(e) IN :empTypes
>
> SELECT TYPE(e)
> FROM Employee e
> WHERE TYPE(e) <> Exempt
> ```

Comment: Is there any way to do this not knowing about any subclasses ?