# Discriminator Java Jpa Class which extends can be type inherenced class

Tags: java, jpa, discriminator

I have one table in a db, and I want to know which type is that instance. I have two entites which are different types. I am having problems.
My first entity is :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lekarfizo")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")  
@DiscriminatorValue("lekar")
```

And the second:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lekarfizo")
@DiscriminatorValue("fizio")  

public class Fizioterapeut extends Lekarfizo
```

The problem is the first entity can be an instance of the second. The second works fine and second can only be instance second entity. I want to know how I can fix that and to make the difference between these two entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an entity type expression with the TYPE operator

```
List<Lekarfizo> rm = em.createQuery("select l from Lekarfizo l where type(l) = Lekarfizo", Lekarfizo.class).getResultList();
System.out.println(rm);
```

Reference: [How do I query for only superclass entities in a jpql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765948/how-do-i-query-for-only-superclass-entities-in-a-jpql-query)