# jpa @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED) how to select super entity not contain child

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have question: Let's assume I have two classes User and person, person extends User. In User I have `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)`. Sometimes I only want to select the user info not contain the child table info,

User.java(super class)

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "user_type")
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {.........}
```

Person.java

```
@Entity
public class Person extends User {......}
```

Company.java

```
@Entity
public class Company extends User {.............}
```

UserRepository.java

```
@Transactional
public interface UserRepository extends UserBaseRepository<User> {

//@Query(value="select u from User u where u.email=?1")
@Query(value="select u.id,u.email from User u where u.email=?1")
User getUser(String email);

@Query("select u from User u where u.email=?1")
User getUser2(String email);

@Query(value="select * from Users where email=:email",nativeQuery=true)
User getUser3(String email);
}
```

The following exception occurs:

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as col_0_0_, user0_.email as col_1_0_ from users user0_ where user0_.email=?
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.Object[] to type netgloo.models.User for value '{1, 635@qq.com}';
nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type java.lang.Long to type netgloo.models.User
```

1. how to  get the user info not contain Person,Company
2. how to  get the Person info not contain user ,Company

Answer (score 2):

To select only the user you can use the JPQL `TYPE()` operator like this:

`SELECT u FROM User u WHERE TYPE(u) := User`

Here is complete explaination: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3766541/534877

Comment: @Query(value="select u from User u where TYPE(u) <> Person and u.email=?1")

Comment: @Query(value="select u from User u where TYPE(u) <> Person and u.email=?1")

Comment: select user0_.id as id2_1_, user0_.email as email3_1_, 
  user0_1_.first_name as first_na1_0_, user0_1_.last_name as last_nam2_0_, 
  user0_.user_type as user_typ1_1_ from users user0_
  
  left outer join person user0_1_ on user0_.id=user0_1_.id 
  
  where 
   case when user0_1_.id is not null then Person
   when user0_.id is not null then 'User' end
   
   <>'Person'
   and user0_.email=?

Comment: in spring jpa the type(u) can't take effect

Comment: from the query sql ,we can see there is still use left jon ,not only select the parent table ,such as select * from user;

Comment: how to only select the parent table ,not join ,sometime there is no need to use join,we only need the parent info