# Spring data JPA to join subclasses in query

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, hql, jpa-2.0

Consider this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_TABLE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    @Type(type= "org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String userName;
}
```

and its simple child:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer extends User{
        //some extra fields
}
```

I have another class having relation to user:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_ACTIVITY")
public class UserActivity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USERID")
    private User user;

    //id and other fields
}
```

This is the tricky part. I want to fetch all objects of type UserActivity which relates to a "Customer". I tried something like this:

```
public interface UserActivityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<UserActivity,UUID> {
    @Query("select u from UserActivity u join Customer.id")
    List<UserActivity> findAllByUserIsNotNullOrderByCreatedDesc(Pageable pageable);
}
```

But hibernate tells me that I've specified an invalid path.

Could you help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly join with `Customer` or filter by `User` ids that belong to `Customer` ids:

1. `select u from UserActivity u, Customer c where u.user.id = c.id`
2. `select u from UserActivity u where u.user.id in (select id from Customer)`

Pick any you like better, as optimizers in modern databases will optimize both queries so that performance is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/DiscriminatorColumn.html) in your `User` entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_TABLE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE")
@DiscriminatorValue("USER")
public class User {

    ...

}
```

Define a [`@DiscriminatorValue("CUSTOMER")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/DiscriminatorValue.html) in your `Customer` entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
@DiscriminatorValue("CUSTOMER")
public class Customer extends User {

    ...

}
```

Query your repository like so

```
@Query("select u from UserActivity u join u.user user where TYPE(user) = 'CUSTOMER'")
List<UserActivity> findAllByUserIsNotNullOrderByCreatedDesc();
```

**Note:** `@DiscriminatorValue` annotation is not mandatory. JPA infers the column name based on the entity type.

Comment: Type takes the entity name, not the DiscriminatorValue.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765948/how-do-i-query-for-only-superclass-entities-in-a-jpql-query

Comment: Yes it does. That's why `TYPE(user)`.  user is the mapped entity.

Comment: That's great that a provider supports it, but JPA requires the entity class as the input parameter, separating the values used in the discriminator column or even the mechanism used in determining classes from the actual type you are looking for.  Your answer about the type is correct, but you don't need to specify the Discriminator annotations at all and just use the class.

Comment: Yeah i tested the above without `@DiscriminatorValue("USER")` and its still running fine. Thanks for the update @Chris