# Spring Jpa inheritance type joined select only baseclass

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I got problem with select only base class and cannot find solution for this.
I always get subclasses too and not only base class.

Consider I have base class

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)   
public class BaseClass {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  private Date date;
  // some fields
}
```

now I inherite

```
@Entity  
public class SubClassA extends BaseClass {
  // some fields
}
interface BaseClassRep extends JpaRepository<BaseClass,Long>{
  @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select id,date from baseclass where date = ?1")
  public BaseClass getByDate(Date date)
}
```

Problem is that BaseClassRep is not only returns BaseClass but SubClassA as well and all other subclasses that inherits from BaseClass.

How to tell Hibernate that I really only want baseclass and not subclasses too.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-entity-type-exp

Comment: I have the same problem too..

Answer (score 1):

you could use type operator.
please look at the following link

[How do I query for only superclass entities in a jpql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765948/how-do-i-query-for-only-superclass-entities-in-a-jpql-query)

or([Java /JPA | Query with specified inherited type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884249/java-jpa-query-with-specified-inherited-type))

```
select id,date from baseclass b where date = ?1 and b.class = ?2
```

Comment: It always create weird long SQL. 
I tried 1) extend JpaRepository and use native query in annotation @Query
  2) work with EntityManager - same result even if i tried with native query again
  So I decied to go lower and use jdbcTemplate. So my SQL statement is actually executed in format I wanted and only collums from base class is returned and nothing else

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance type:

`@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`
, then your create a repository for the superclass and you fetch your data.